# ASP.NET MVC - Losing Session After Redirect From 3rd Party (Moneris Hosted Payment Page)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, session, session-cookies

Running a typical ASP.NET MVC site with a simple payment page.    Our app does a FORM POST and sends the user to Moneris's Hosted Payment Page - and upon successful payment, the user is redirected back to our site (a payment response route) where we parse the payment response from Moneris.

- We are always losing the User's session as soon as they are redirected back.
- We are using Session State Service (with a long timeout) on a Load Balanced environment.
- Our site, as well as the Moneris payment page are using HTTPS
- We are not using cookieless sessions

Would greatly appreciate any feedback on what we may be doing wrong to be losing sessions.